# Recover lost POST data on LAMP site

Tags: apache-2.2, mysql, php, ubuntu-12.04

I've had a screwup on my LAMP based site where a certain string value that's posted to the site from a form, was not being stored in the db.  The db column for it was an enum but it needed to be a varchar.  Strangely mysql didnt throw an error when running the INSERT sql from   the site's PHP code. 
 The mysql bin logs were not enabled, so I can't use that. I was thinking maybe the Apache logs, but that doesnt seem to have the POST data.

Is there any possible way to recover this?
The OS is ubuntu 12.04

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That data is gone. By default, apache does not log data that is POSTed.

There are ways to enable this logging, but you would have had to enable this prior to the incident.

Comment: Indeed.  The issue here is that POST data is not part of the request, *per se*.  It's simple stream IO on STDIN for the process being launched (e.g. PHP as in this case, or a CGI script).  Thus, you can't simply modify your `LogFomat` to pick it up; you have to do the in-process moral equivalent of `tee`.  Point being, the data is not only gone, it would also have been rather hard to collect in the first place.